# VBA Runtime Error going from Excel 2003 to 2016

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that was built with Macros in Excel 2003, which we no longer have available to us. I'm trying to run it in Excel 2016, and am trying to work through the macro errors that are appearing.

I'm somewhat capable with VBA, but by no means an expert, and as I didn't write these macros, I'm starting from scratch.

I get a `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error` on the .Group.Select line in the below code.

```
'Group all shapes into one box
With .Range(Array(sPutName, sTriName, sBoxName(0), sBoxName(1), sBoxName(2), _
        sBoxName(3), sBoxName(4), sBoxName(5), sBoxName(6), sBoxName(7)))
    sPutGrouped = "put" + Trim(str(puts - iPutStart + 1))
    .Group.Select
    .name = sPutGrouped
End With
```

Any advice on where to start looking?

*EDIT*

So it appears to be related to the below code, which appears immediately before the above snippet.

```
' A work around (HACK) to allow grouping of all the shapes
'  basically fills the remaining array elements with last one
            While sBoxName(box) = "" And (box < 8)
                sBoxName(box) = sBoxName(box - 1)
                box = box + 1
            Wend
```

Essentially, the macro draws a number of boxes between 1 and 8. If it only draws 2, then sBoxName(2) to sBoxName(8) are set to the same as sBoxName(1). If I know how many boxes it is going to draw beforehand, and delete the reference to the duplicate boxes from the .Range Array, then everything works. However, I need this statement to work with any number of boxes between 1 and 8.

Comment: debug and share the values of all your variables please

Comment: The place to start is to figure out what/where each of the "things" named in the Array are.  They could be names of arrays, functions, etc,.  The comment mentions shapes so those could be controls or boxes, etc, on a worksheet, but probably not the ones with `(_)` numbers at the end.   CTRL+F to and search `entire project` to look for more clues about those items in the code.  If you've never worked with this code before, you're going to need to step through all of it line-by-line (ie., F8), likely repeatedly, to figure out what it all does.

Comment: Also [here is a link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) to an overview of **Debugging VBA** (such as "stepping through code"), and is one of numerous guides I recommend you check out from Chip Pearson, the Excel/VBA Guru.

Comment: Thanks - edited the above post after following through the array elements.

Comment: It looks like you try to group multiple shapes and then select this group in one line. If there is no error on With statement, then we can assume that shapes with such names exist. Try the same without With statement, one line assigning .Group to variable and another with this variable representing group using .Select. Sometimes in VBA With statement does not allow you to continue working on a subject of With line, as it was modified within this block. Grouping might be such modification.

Comment: @ashleedawg: is there an update somewhere on the status and long-term plan for Chip's work?

Comment: @AJD - your note prompted me to search my emails and realized I'd overlooked a few, including from the gentleman who's had the site brought back up.  Could you please email me, ashleedawg [at] outlook (dot) com and I should have more of an update by that point.  Thanks - (i hope I haven't missed any other messages on here, I've been swamped with unrelated messages on here)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the code against a worksheet with some boxes (check the With statement above the one you gave in your example, to see which sheet the code is running against).

Try halting the code at

```
With .Range(Array(sPutName, sTriName, sBoxName(0), sBoxName(1), sBoxName(2), _
        sBoxName(3), sBoxName(4), sBoxName(5), sBoxName(6), sBoxName(7)))
```

Then in the immediate window, type:

```
?.Range(Array(sPutName, sTriName, sBoxName(0), sBoxName(1), sBoxName(2), _
        sBoxName(3), sBoxName(4), sBoxName(5), sBoxName(6), sBoxName(7))).address
```

You should get a valid cell reference string, such as "A1:A3,D2:D3".  My guess is that you won't... and a solution to the problem may appear.

Comment: Immediate window will not recognize range starting with a point. Parent of this range must be specified earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by creating an array and using ReDim to append the name of each box to the end of the array as the box was created. This meant the array was always the correct length for the actual number of boxes created, and I could delete the second code snippet above.